# How to link a folder to a build in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I create a folder in my custom workspace using "execute shell" step, and put some files there. The name of the folder is generated based on the current date, and all the folders from all builds should be available.

Is it possible to somehow link this folder to a build, so that when the build gets removed, so does it's folder?

Comment: Is it like you want to tag "2018-01-01" to build #123 and when build #123 is removed, folder "2018-01-01" too will be removed automatically?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Right now I need to regularly clear the output manually. I want for jenkins to remove them automatically, together with the old builds.